# Invalid URI when trying to convert it into bitmap

Tags: android

what I want to do is have the user choose a contact and then set the corresponding imageView from my application as the contact's photo (if any). With what I have written so far  I can get the URI of the contact's photo but then I get this exception `read failed: EINVAL (invalid argument)` at first I thought it could be because of a null value though the URI I get is `content://com.android.contacts/contacts/1/photo` is this an invalid URI? the way I try to set it in the imageView is as follows:

```
            if (myUri != null){
            try {
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getActivity().getContentResolver().openInputStream(myUri));
                firstImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);              
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) { 
                ;
            }
```

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the READ_CONTACTS permission you are able to do this:

```
Uri myUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, contactId);

if (myUri != null){
    try {
        InputStream in = ContactsContract.Contacts
                .openContactPhotoInputStream(getActivity().getContentResolver(), myUri);
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        firstImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);              
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) { 
            ;
}
```

Comment: i have nearly the exact code as above and for me it works. Maybe something is wrong with your uri. I added the line of code how i build up the Uri. Maybe that helps

Comment: Ok that was it. Apparently the uri had a problem. Thank you very much!